# "Yeah, no, I agree" meaning

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

This is a passage in the movie *The Social Network* at 01:14:49:

> Mark says: "Yeah, that reminds me, we're gonna need more money, Wardo."
>   Eduardo replies: "**Yeah, no, I agree.** More servers, more help."

(Emphasis mine.) I want to know why Eduardo says "no" after "yeah". How can he use them both in the same sentence? Is this an idiom?

Note that the quote is based on the subtitles, so I didn't mishear a "yeah, I know" or anything like that.

Comment: You'll have to provide a link, so we can listen; but I betcha what he says is actually "Yeah, **I know**, I agree."

Comment: it's not an idiom and obviously we don't have the full conversation here!

Comment: @StoneyB It's not unlikely that the character said "Yeah, no, I agree." I'm not the one to ask why but it's certainly said colloquially.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of "No, yes ..."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/meaning-of-no-yes)

Comment: *Yeah*: "I hear you." *No*: "No, I'm not arguing." Or something like that. These are phatic expressions meant to communicate meta-information about the conversation rather than to provide pure information about the topic being discussed.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok  You're quite right. The script's online, and that's what it calls for. Something for author, director and actor to work out.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=little+britain+yeah+but+no&oq=little+britain+yeah+but+no&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.4591j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) is Vicky Pollard demonstrating the phenomenon.

Comment: It's not unusual for the word "no" to be used in the same sense as "uh", as the person is thinking of the next word to say.  It's best to not assign any significance to it.

Answer (score 8):

I've said it myself conversationally. Its generally used when the person you are talking to is expecting an argument back from you, or for some reason thinks you disagree with them on a point, when in fact you don't.

I always pictured the "Yeah" as going with the stated argument, and the "No, I agree" as applying to the person's unstated statement that you need convincing on that point.

Its sort of a conversational palliative for when you're talking with someone who is getting worked up over a point that you don't feel is actually in contention.

Answer (score 7):

I can't answer for sure about this particular usage, however, there **are** contexts where someone might say, "Yeah, no, I agree." Consider:

> Ed: We should take off the covers, and then drain the fluid.
>   Ted: That would make a mess; we should drain the fluid first.
>   Ed: *Yeah, no, I agree*.

What Ed means is:

> ***Yes***, you're right; **no**, we don't *want to the covers off first – **I agree** with you.*

I'd back the recording up, and see if maybe Eduardo says something that Mark is disagreeing with when he makes his statement. If so, then my example might unlock the mystery.

Either way, it's not idiomatic speech, it's simply situational. There is a related ELU question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/meaning-of-no-yes).

Comment: I don't think it matters if Mark is in disagreement. It's bad English (nonsensical) to use it when you're in agreement but I think it's similar to "um" in the way that people say it without thinking about it.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok: Um, yeah, no, I guess – sometimes it can indicate indecisiveness or something. :^)

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously not a precise way to speak, but certainly very common in casual conversation. It can reflect an in-conversation change in opinion: Yeah (to what was just said), no (to what was said prior), I agree (confirm new stance).

During casual conversation the context doesn't need to be spelled out at every turn, it's assumed that the participants are following along and can fill in the blanks. Taken out of context, snippets of conversation can be confusing, vague, and often quite fun.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a speech-language pathologist who works with teens with autism, so I'm always looking at language usage that is confusing for people who tend to take things very literally.

I've been thinking about "yeah, no" a lot recently. I don't know as I would say it's a phatic expression, because it nearly always seems to have the purpose of being an affirmative. I see it as a way to downplay or diminish the emphasis of an affirmative response, as if to tacitly state you're not disagreeing with the first speaker, but also possibly to try to make your own identical opinion seem like it's somehow more valid. It's very frequent these days.

On TV I see both men and women use it, but in my real life it's nearly always said to me (female) by men, when I state an opinion they agree with. More information is always added after "yeah, no."

Example: me (to a male): "You guys need a doorbell."
Him: "Yeah, no, we definitely do; I just haven't gotten one yet."

Another example: 
Me (to a male): Shouldn't we get this report in soon?"
Him: "Yeah, no, it's definitely due this week."

Comment: I've regarded it as a (self-protecting) hedge: 'Yes [you're right,/; no [I'm not so keen on the implied criticism.]'

Answer (score 0):

I hear this all of the time in California. In these cases, these are just filler words, like "umm", "like", and "you know". They drive people with any linguistic sensibility crazy.

Comment: People "with any linguistic sensibility" ought to be aware of [phatic expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression). I'm pretty sure linguistics scholars have written whole dissertations on them, in fact.

Comment: Uh, yeah. I think. Is it getting cold in here? ;-)

Comment: @Robusto - Hmmm. I think that was the point I was trying to get at in my answer. Didn't know there was a name for it.

Answer (score -1):

I hear one of my colleagues use "yeah no" very frequently (to the point of annoyance). It is always used in a manner of affirmation but a kind of rolling back the affirmation almost to downplay it, as if the first "yeah" was too enthusiastic and the following "no" is to introduce an element of taking control from the first speaker and/or self deprecation (very common in England). At the same time it has the effect of playing down the significance of what the other person was saying and is also a kind of hedging as mentioned above. A very strange 'tick' and not a good one in my view.